# Contextual filter based on translated term

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views, entities, i18n-l10n

I'm looking two days for the right answer but can't find it anywhere.

Here is my issue:

I'm using Drupal 7.21 with Entity Translation to build a multilangual site (English and Dutch). English is the default language. I have a vocabulary 'Sections' with the terms (lets say) Section 1, Section 2, Section 3, Section 4 and Section 5. Each term is translated to Dutch with the Entity Translation module.

I have also a content type 'Case', with a term reference field 'Section'. When I add a Case 'Case example' with section 'Section 1' the generated URL-alias will be 'section-1/cases/case-example'.
When I translate 'Case example' to Dutch, the generated URL-alias will be 'section-1-du/cases/case-voorbeeld-1'.

The site contains five sections and each section contains its own cases.

I use Views (1 View, 1 Display) to display a case-overview per section. To achieve this, I've done these steps:

- Add a contextual filter 'Content: Has taxonomy term ID'.
- When the filter value is not available:

  - Provide default value
  - Type: Raw value from URL
  - Path component: 1
  - Check 'Use path alias'
- When the filter value is available or a default is provided:

  - Check 'Specify validation criteria'
  - Validator: 'Taxonomy Term'
  - Check vocabulary 'Sections'
  - Filter value type: 'Term name converted to Term ID'
  - Check 'Transform dashes in URL to spaces in term name filter values'
  - Action to take if filter value does not validate: 'Hide view'

So here is my problem. If I look at the page 'section-1/cases' everything works fine. But when I look at the Dutch page 'section-1-du/cases', the view doesn't show anything.

My question: How is it possible to use a entity-translated term as contextual filter?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Your 'Raw Value' changes with language. You should try Type Taxonomy term ID from URL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Triskelion. But when I use 'Taxonomy term ID from URL' the view stays empty. I suppose I should use this option if the taxonomy term is the last component of the URL. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: There's some preliminary code for this in the [feature request](https://www.drupal.org/node/2378991), in the Entity Translation issue queue.